# Base64 image when converted to File Object has a weird name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, file-io, base64

```
var b64 = newCroppedImage.split(',');
var file = [];
file.push(new File([window.atob(b64[1])], {type: 'image/jpeg'}));
```

The code above creates a new image `File()` object which is going to be uploaded to Amazon S3. The problem is that the `file.name` for every `base64` image which is being converted is always `"objec Object"` (see image below), resulting to similar file names for image for every `File()` object. Why is that? Is there a way to change it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @elio.d I don't understand sorry, what do you mean "fix the attachment"?

Comment: The image you attached is not visible

Comment: How about now?  @elio.d

Comment: here http://i.stack.imgur.com/MgOz1.png

Comment: well now you have attached it twice :)... anyway back to the topic.. not sure if on the constructor you can pass the name as a second parameter. s first paramter the data, second the name, third the mime type. Otherwise you can build your file using a blob that for sure take a filename as a parameter

Comment: I didnt remove the first one for assurance :). Anyways, if I use `Blob()` can I upload it to s3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
var b64 = newCroppedImage.split(',');
var file = [];
file.push(new File([window.atob(b64[1])], 'file.jpeg', {type: 'image/jpeg'}));
```

Comment: In this case where did the cropped image went? And where does `cnv` come from?

Comment: updated using your exact code so you don't get confused

Comment: Nice, but how about the `file extension? ` how do I know If Im going to use jpeg or png?

Comment: well you exported the base64 from the canvas using toDataURL, if you don't provide any parameter to this method, by default it will export a png otherwise you can tell the canvas to export a jpeg doing drawImage('image/jpeg') in this case you can provide another parameter for the image quality (a number between 0 and 1)